# Windows 7 - Move open programs more freely on the taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

When I used Windows XP last year, I had a program called Taskix which let me move the tabs in the taskbar around for programs in any order I wanted. Now that I have Windows 7, a similar function comes built into the operating system - however, it isn't as flexible as Taskix was in XP.

Theoretical situation:
1. Open a folder named #1
2. In folder #1, open an instance of a program
3. Open a folder named #2
4. In folder #2, open an instance of the same program that was opened in step 2.

After doing this, I will have (in order, on the taskbar) 2 folders open and 2 instances of the programs open.

My question really is: Is there any way to fight this automatic ordering of tabs on the taskbar? A registry hack or something would be best, but if there's a third party program out there, that would be nice to know about.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) would let you do that and much more:

[image]